# Using an if-statement for div by 0 protection in Modelica

Tags: if-statement, modelica

I made a simple model of a heat pump which uses sensor data to calculate its COP.

while COP = heat / power

sometimes there is no power so the system does a (cannot divide by zero). I would like these values to just be zero. So i tried an IF-statement[if-statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZANy.png). if power(u) = 0 then COP(y) = 0. somehow this does not work (see time 8)[COP output + data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcS0e.png). Anyone who seems to notice the problem?

edit(still problems at time 8.1 [image: output2.o] [image: textview 2.0]
edit(heat and power) [image: heat/power/COP]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the computation a bit more generally applicable (e.g. the sign of power can change), take a look at the code below. It could also be a good idea to build a function from it (for the function the noEvent()-statements can be left out)...

```
model DivNoZeroExample
      parameter Real eps = 1e-6 "Smallest number to be used as divisor";
      Real power = 0.5-time "Some artificial value for power";
      Real heat = 1 "Some artificial value for heat";
      Real COP "To be computed";

equation 
    if noEvent(abs(power) < abs(eps)) then
        COP =  if noEvent(power>= 0) then heat/eps else heat/(-eps);
    else
        COP =  heat/power;
    end if;
end DivNoZeroExample;
```

Comment: Although i'm not to sure what is going on with the 'eps' value. It worked. the COP goes down to 0. Still at tiem 8.1 the COP goes back to 11 again. when it should not. any ideas in this?

Comment: Can you add `power` and `heat` in your plot?

Comment: I added the power and heat. any change you know the problem?

Comment: Can you give a short description of how you got rid of it? Could be helpful for others...

Comment: I used the CombiTimeTable from the modelica standard library to store the data. The stepsize on default is a really small number. I set it to 1 and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Relational operations work a bit differently in Modelica.

If you replace `if u>0` by `if noEvent(u>0)` it should work as you expected.

For details see section 8.5 Events and Synchronization in the Modelica specification https://modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately it did not solve the problem. Can it be possible that is has to do with the CombiTimeTable i'm using?